How to create a fail2ban filter to protect a FastAPI implementation?
Im working on a FastAPI project but I want to implement a fail2ban filter that blocks all abusive intents on my API.
So far i have created a log file that stores all API requests in a access.log file
2024-05-09 09:02:20,013 | 172.20.101.226 | GET | /prediccion/1097116902/1543113/2024-01-02T15:10/fcv1234/ | 307
2024-05-09 09:44:44,450 | 172.20.101.226 | GET | /prediccion/1097116902/1543113/2024-01-02T15:10/fcv1234/ | 307
2024-05-09 09:45:29,932 | 172.20.101.226 | GET | /prediccion/1097116902/1543113/2024-01-02T15:10/fcv1234/ | 307
2024-05-09 09:55:27,145 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | /favicon.ico | 404
2024-05-09 10:05:46,924 | 172.20.101.226 | GET | /prediccion/1097116902/1543113/2024-01-02 15:10:00/fcv1234 | 200
2024-05-09 10:08:47,131 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:47,227 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | /favicon.ico | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:48,262 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:48,845 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:49,292 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:49,676 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:49,997 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:50,306 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404
2024-05-09 10:08:50,531 | 172.20.100.105 | GET | / | 404

And the filter in sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/fastapi.conf
[Definition]
failregex = ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \| <HOST> \| GET \| .* \| 404

And the jail.local file was modified by adding this
[fastapi]
enabled  = true
filter   = fastapi
port     = 5002
logpath  = /home/admonda/py/PMV/access.log
maxretry = 5
findtime = 600
bantime  = 3600

I cannot get it to work. Even if I perform multiple 404 errors via web browser, my ip address never gets banned.
Running some tests with fail2ban-regex /home/admonda/py/PMV/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/fastapi.conf, yield this output
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : fastapi, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /home/admonda/py/PMV/access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [104] {^LN-BEG}ExYear(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day(?:T|  ?)24hour:Minute:Second(?:[.,]Microseconds)?(?:\s*Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 104 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 104 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 104 lines


fail2ban already knows how to recognize dates... Your first regex isn't realley needed. Also, to split your line in fields, why the | char?
